# Library linkage in makefile using gfortran

Tags: linux, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I have a fortran code (pardiso_1.f) and it needs some libraries (BLAS, lapack and Pardiso libraries) to be compiled. When I try to compile it, I link libraries before compilation and I write this line in linux terminal:

```
gfortran pardiso_1.f  -L/home/behnam/Pardiso -lpardiso412-GNU450-X86-64 -L/usr/lib -lblas -llapack -fopenmp
```

and it works perfectly.

However I have to run the code using makefile. I am so new in writing makefiles and I do not know how to do the linkage. I have written this makefile. could anyone help me to find out what is wrong with that?

```
FC = gfortran
OPT = -O2
PROGRAMS = pardiso_1

all: $(PROGRAMS)
FFLAGS = -fopenmp

#### BLAS, LAPACK and PTHREAD libraries
LBLAS = /usr/lib/

###location of pardiso file
LIBMKL = /home/behnam/PS2/

#### Series of libraries
LIBRARIES= -llapack -lblas -lpthread -lm -lpardiso412-GNU430-X86-64

PATHFC = /usr/bin/

nlace: ${PATHFC}${FC} ${OPT} ${FFLAGS} -I${PROGRAMS} -o nlace.exe \
         -L${LIBMKL} -lpardiso412-GNU430-X86-64\
         -L${LBLAS} ${LIBRARIES}


clean:
    rm -f *.o *.exe fort.* *~ *.mod

veryclean: clean
    rm -f *~ $(PROGRAMS)
```

---

The errors are:

```
behnam@meen-392430:~/testing$ make
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 23 s in the future
gfortran -fopenmp   pardiso_1.f   -o pardiso_1
/tmp/ccYNexaH.o: In function `MAIN__':
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `pardisoinit_'
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `pardiso_chkmatrix_'
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0x36e): undefined reference to `pardiso_chkvec_'
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0x44c): undefined reference to `pardiso_printstats_'
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0x5ae): undefined reference to `pardiso_'
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0x860): undefined reference to `pardiso_'
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0xb78): undefined reference to `pardiso_'
pardiso_1.f:(.text+0xe00): undefined reference to `pardiso_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pardiso_1] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile does not contain the `-L/home/behnam/Pardiso` part of your command line.

Comment: /home/behnam/PS2/ is the same as /home/behnam/Pardiso

Comment: @behnamm: look at your error code. Note how it says, `gfortran -fopenmp   pardiso_1.f   -o pardiso_1` and does not include `-L/home/behnam/PS2`?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule for `PROGRAMS` does not contain a recipe that includes the library calls.  I presume you want something like your `nlace` rule, but right now, make is not calling any of your `-L` switches as part of its operation.